# What are the benefits of compiling with -j1 instead of -jN

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Compiling with `-jN` will compile faster, because it's compiling several parts at the same time. But GCC docs say (I can't find the exact link though) that compiling with `-j1` will produce a better optimized binary.

Can you explain all the benefits of compiling with `-j1`? Can you even provide a small POC that proves that compiling with `-j1` generates a more optimized (in performance terms) binary than `-jN`?

Comment: I'd like to have the link to the claim.

Comment: If I had to speculate, I'd say that multithreaded compilation might not apply interprocedural optimizations across chunks of code being compiled in different threads.

Comment: You are probably thinking about whole program optimization. When gcc sees only 1 file it is limited to what it can optimize, because unknown external code could depend on the behavior. If gcc sees the whole program it can figure out exactly which code depends how on what, allowing better optimization. It makes no difference whether you use -j1 to let gcc compile one file at a time or -jN to compile all of them concurrently. However, it does make a difference whether you let one instance compile everything with one call or every file separately with separate calls.

Comment: @nwp Yes, I was talking about that, I just didn't know how to express it. Thank you! Can you point me to some more docs or elaborate a little bit further in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably thinking about whole program optimization. When gcc sees only 1 file it is limited to what it can optimize, because unknown external code could depend on the behavior, so it is very hard to completely optimize things away. If gcc sees the whole program it can figure out exactly which code depends how on what, allowing better optimization. It makes no difference whether you use -j1 to let gcc compile one file at a time or -jN to compile all of them concurrently. However, it does make a difference whether you let one instance compile everything with one call or one every file separately with separate calls.

Reference: [The compiler performs optimization based on the knowledge it has of the program. Compiling multiple files at once to a single output file mode allows the compiler to use information gained from all of the files when compiling each of them.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Answer (score 2):

-j option is for make. There's no such option for gcc

I think you are talking about -O option.

Here's the man page for -O1

> ```
>    -O1 Optimize.  Optimizing compilation takes somewhat more time, and a lot more memory for a large function. 
>    With -O, the compiler tries to reduce code size and execution time, without performing any optimizations that take a great deal of compilation time.
> ```

Comment: `-j` is, as you say, an option in `make` that does nothing more but launch several instances of GCC. Imho my question is correct: "Does a single instance of GCC produce better optimized binaries than multiple instances of GCC".

Comment: May I ask where did you get that conclusion?

Comment: I recall reading it somewhere in GCC docs, but I can't find that text right now (I'm trying to find it though).